# Unable to uninstall managed beta package throws internal server error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, beta-managed-package, uninstall

I've been trying to uninstall a managed beta package that I have in another dev org (3 dev orgs), but I keep getting an internal server error like below:

[image]

I made sure nothing is dependent on the beta package, like being used in a community page. Also, this is a Lightning Component.

I have no easy way of contacting Salesforce. I figured I would ask here and see if anyone else is experiencing this issue?

Comment: Usually if there is a dependency, you'll be presented with a page that tells you what those dependencies are. I haven't see this before, so possibly related to being a lightning component.

Comment: I had this problem once uploading a managed package and the fix was to compile all classes. Doubtful that it will work here as the situation is different but you could give it a shot. Also, try deleting all data that it holds first. Maybe something happens when data is being deleted that causes the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and it's my error. When you want to install a managed beta package, you need to ensure that all your communities are not using the component. This includes both published and un-published communities. When you have a published community using the managed beta package component, you'll need to republish the community without the beta package.